# How can I determine which SSH keyfile was used to authenticate a login?

Tags: ssh, logs, authentication, key-authentication

We have a hosted CentOS 6.5 server in which we have a single user account.  That account has been configured to use SSH keyfile authentication for the users who need to access it.

I would like to be able to see which keyfile was used to authenticate each login; effectively telling me which end-user logged into the single unix user account.  Is there a mechanism for doing so?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick there is not auth.log on CentOS.

Comment: @Jakuje Thank you. I’ve removed my comment that mentioned that file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On CentOS there is `/var/log/secure`. This holds the fingerprints of the logins:

```
 Aug  7 23:12:57 my-server sshd[2584]: Accepted publickey for user from 192.168.1.156 port 58279 ssh2: RSA 32:f1:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:bb:be:ef:c3:aa:bb:cc:f8
```

Map these back to the keys and you have the info you need.
You can get the key fingerprints by doing:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/*.pub
```