# How to use private-key to setup password-less ssh on new machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have one machine say `source1` and there is passwordless ssh already set to more than 100 server say  `remote1`, `remote2`, ...`remote100`.

Now I need to set similar setup of passwordless ssh on another server `source2` and I dont want to copy the public key of `source2` to authorized_keys file of all hundred server.

Can I use the private key of server `source1` to set similar setup on `source2`? How to achieve that? I heard of `ssh-agent` is one of the way but could not understand much on the steps.

Comment: client authentication is to authenticate a user, not a machine.

Comment: yes..I am using root user

Comment: The setting up can be handled automatically with a simple loop. `for remote in $(seq 100); do cat public_key.pub | ssh "remote$remote" tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; done`. Unless all your remote use the same `authorized_keys` file, you'll have to edit all of them.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith, `ssh "$remote" 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' < public_key.pub`. Otherwise you'll overwrite the authorized_keys (and ~ on the remote host may not be the same as on the local host).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Added `-a` just now and posted an slightly more detailed answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If all your remotes have their own root user (that is, different `/root` directories), with their own `authorized_keys` file, you'll need to edit all of them all in order to add a new key:

```
for remote in $(seq 100); do 
    cat public_key.pub | ssh "remote$remote" tee -a .ssh/authorized_keys
done
```

However, you could also send your source1's private key to source2. This way, both machines will use the same key pair (which is already registered by all the remotes). I don't think this could create any kind of conflicts, yet having two keys seems more natural to me. Fact is, since all your machines are probably on the same network, and managed by the same user, having one key compromised would probably breach the whole system. Therefore, having two wouldn't bring that much more security (since one is enough to become root somewhere).

Comment: The `~` is expanded on the local machine, you want it expanded on the remote machine (assuming the login shell of the remote user supports it). But the remote command's cwd normally starts in the user's home directory so you can do `tee -a .ssh/authorized_keys` or `'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'`

Comment: Since the OP is setting up a root key pair, `~` would be expanded to `/root` anyway. I'll edit my answer, thank you.

Comment: You're right; using one key would not create conflicts, and having two keys is no more safe against compromise than having one key on two machines.  But if source1's key did get compromised, having different keys could help with cleanup afterwards since you wouldn't have to replace source2's key (and source3's, etc).  With careful logging, you could also tell which key (and therefore which machine) was compromised: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15575

Answer (score 0):

The approach to take depends on the specific scenario. It would be nicest if there already is a key that exists in the user’s `authorized_keys` on all of the servers that can be used to authenticate when adding the new key to the remote hosts, because otherwise you have to type in your password for each host.

The simplest way to automate copying a ssh key to a remote machine is using `ssh-copy-id`, and if you have servers called `remote1` through `remote100` it could be done using something like the following:

```
for server in $(seq -f 'remote%.0f' 1 100); do
    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa "$server"
done
```

Which would automatically take the public key for `id_rsa`, ssh into all of the servers in sequence, and add the public key to `authorized_keys`. If this is the only key you would have on the servers you will be prompted for your password to add them though, since the `ssh-copy-id` program needs to actually ssh into the servers.

One way to automate it even further would be to use something like `expect` to automate logging in with a password since OpenSSH’s ssh client doesn’t have a command-line option to specify the password, or alternatively by using a wrapper like `sshpass`.