# sshd not starting after boot on embedded linux built with buildroot?

Tags: embedded, raspberry-pi, busybox, init.d, buildroot

I've done a minimal install using buildroot's default config for the Raspberry Pi. I also selected openssh and openssl from menuconfig:

```
Package Selection for the target  --->
    [*] Networking  --->
        [*]   openssh
    [*] Library -->
        Crypto -->
            -*-   openssl
            [*]      openssl binary
            [ ]      openssl additional engines
```

I assigned the Pi to `192.168.0.14`, but couldn't ssh to it. nmap shows all ports are closed for the Pi, and sometimes doesn't show the Pi at all, which I found odd - the LINK LED blinks whenever nmap scans it, so I guess it's connected just fine.

I usually manage startup services with `update-rc.d` or `systemctl`, however I can only connect to the Pi via ssh - I have no HDMI or Serial Port. I'm unsure how to set it up manually. `/etc/init.d/S50sshd` is present in the Pi so it should be starting ssh after boot, shouldn't it?

Relevant config files: [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://pastebin.com/ganQP5rJ), [`/etc/init.d/S50sshd`](http://pastebin.com/x0U6ULbW).

I couldn't find any relevant logs in the SD card.

Edit:

Following X Tian's suggestion from the comments I was able to obtain the logs. The only thing logged was [`/var/log/messages`](http://pastebin.com/5GcE24zq). Relevant part:

```
Jan  1 00:00:02 buildroot auth.info sshd[75]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
```

It seems sshd is starting. The issue seems to be something else.

```
root@pc:~# ssh 192.168.0.14
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.14 port 22: Connection refused
root@pc:~# ping 192.168.0.14
PING 192.168.0.14 (192.168.0.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=32.8 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.14: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=55.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.14: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=79.1 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.14 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 32.808/55.871/79.140/18.917 ms
root@pc:~# exit
debian@pc:~ nmap -F 192.168.0.14
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-30 03:25 BRT

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.14
Host is up (0.085s latency).
All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.0.14 are closed
```

Funny thing is, after shutting down the Pi and disconnecting the Ethernet cable I was still able to ping that address. Now I'm really lost. I figured it'd be best to just tar and upload [all files under /](http://a.pomf.se/fvlypw.tar.gz) if someone knows where to look at (it's not a production environment, the passwords and private keys are not in use, they were set for test purposes).

Comment: I noticed that /var/log is a link to ../tmp try removing it and create a real /var/log directory, hopefully then the log file will be retained between reboots - I'm guessing if you can't access via ssh and have no console, you are looking at the sdcard between reboots.

Comment: @Alex "I was still able to ping that address" -> Seems to be a network issue. You could have 2 devices with the same IP address. Check your DHCP server (if any) and your static devices. You could use `arp` to check MAC addresses of the `192.168.0.14` device and compare to the RPi one.

Comment: I fully agree with the jml analysis. This will explain both a ghost reply to a ping and a lack of reply from sshd: *duplicate @IP*!

Comment: @jml: please make an answer of your analysis: right & simple.

Comment: raise the logging level on sshd, to check what's happening, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Your sshd_config does not permit empty passwords you are logging in as root and the root account does not have a password set.

change the ssh_config

```
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

to

```
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

To get more info into the log, try raising the logging level for ssh

From

```
#LogLevel INFO
```

to

```
LogLevel DEBUG
```

Read futher about changing sshd log levels in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15586/31760).

Answer (score 2):

In your analysis you said:

> After shutting down the Pi and disconnecting the Ethernet cable I was still able to ping that address

This is a duplicate IP symptom. In other word, you have 2 (or more) devices with the same IP address.

You should check the MAC address of your device using this 2 ways:

One your device, do a `ifconfig` and check the `HWaddr` field.

```
root@rpi# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B8:27:EB:BE:1C:67  
          inet addr:192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

One your remote computer, do a `arp -a <device IPaddr>` and check the `ether` field`.

```
jml@pc$ arp -a 192.168.1.11
? (192.168.1.11) at b8:27:eb:be:1c:67 [ether] on eth0
```

On my example, both MAC address are the same. If not, you will have to check all the IP address of your network (static **and** dynamic).

Most of the time this issue is due to a misconfiguration of a DHCP server used with other static address. By example, if your DHCP server have a pool between `192.168.1.10` and `192.168.1.20`, you **must not** have other static address within this range.

To get back to your Pi issue. Just try to assign it a new IP address which is not in your DHCP range. Or reconfigure your DHCP server to let more space for your static addresses.

Comment: Most definitively a misdiagnosed (because of the previous absence of sshd logs) network issue. I'm not running a DHCP server and the only computers with physical access to the network are my desktop (`192.168.0.10`) and the Pi (`192.168.0.14`). I tried assigning a different IP address anyway, to no avail. I also disabled the router firewall. I even tried *enabling* the DHCP server to see what happened, but it only made things worse, as it wouldn't assign the Pi an IP address. Now I'm getting `No route to host`, which confirms the network issue. I'll try tomorrow with a different router. Thanks

Comment: @Alex jml is correct - if you can still `ping` your RasperryPi when it is disconnected and off, then **you are not pinging RasperryPi** but something else, and you **have to** resolve that issue before even trying anything else (or you'll be in word of pain)

Answer (score 0):

> /etc/init.d/S50sshd is present in the Pi so it should be starting ssh after boot, shouldn't it?

Not exactly. The `/etc/init.d/S50sshd` file is used, but what is called is the file from the appropiate runlevel folder. When you run `update-rc.d` it simply creates symlinks to the S50sshd in init.d at the required `/etc/rc?.d/` folders.

You can view the current status with:

```
ls etc/rc*.d/*ssh*
```

(I would expect it to be present on runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5)

And create them with:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc2.d
ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc3.d
ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc4.d
ln -s /etc/init.d/ssh /etc/rc5.d
```

Comment: BusyBox init has no runlevels AFAIK.

Comment: @Alex, Is it generating a runlevel-less system? From your Raspberry Pi mention, I assumed a Raspbian system, which seem to have runlevels.

Comment: As I mentioned, I've done a minimal install using buildroot. It's nor Raspbian.

Comment: This could be an issue with either the source or the destination firewall, or sshd not running/listening. Can you log in to the Pi without ssh?  IF yes, then please try `netstat -tulpanw` as `root` to see whether `sshd` is up and listening on port 22. If not, try starting it up manually, like `sshd -D &` as `root`.

Answer (score 0):

**No router + regular Ethernet cable + RPI 2 + Buildroot  2016.05 + Ubuntu 16.04 host**

Got it working after I've split this problem into two parts:

1. get ethernet SSH working with Raspbian and a direct cable connection (which already has a properly setup sshd daemon running) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54394/33424
2. learn how to do a proper sshd configuration on QEMU + buildroot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39301480/895245

   On the real board, you don't have a QEMU window to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of course, so you will need to either:

   - modify it on host before flashing (either `BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY`, mount `output/images/sdcard.img` with https://askubuntu.com/a/496576/52975 , or play with `output/target`)
   - connect via UART TTL. You will want to get this working sooner or later, as it is the best way to debug your buildroot distro on the board.

`.config` is simply `raspberrypi2_defconfig` + `openssh` enabled with `make menuconfig`.

Then just:

```
ssh "root@$(cat /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases | cut -d ' ' -f 3)"
```

[image]
[image]

TTL on image only used for power.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well with buildroot. Turns out that sshd was failing to  start despite etc/init.d/S50sshd due to /var/empty permissions (the hint came from looking closely at console prints)

```
Starting sshd: /var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.

# ls -l /var/                                                                                                                                                                                               
total 0                                                                                                                                                                                                     
..                                                                                                                                 
drwxr-xr-x    2 sshd     sshd            40 Jan  1 00:09 empty
```

My solution was to delete it, recreate it (I was already root)

```
# ls -l /var/                                                                                                                                                                                               
total 0                                                                                                                                                                                                     
..                                                                                                                                 
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            40 Jan  1 00:09 empty
```

And then start sshd manually.